# How to play different audio files on a single page

Tags: javascript, html, web, audio

I would like to play different short audio clips on a single page by using different buttons, however the code I have means that *all* buttons will play only the first .mp3 located in the audio folder regardless of the html code I have that specifies which button will play which audio clip (example below).

Could you help me with the code to figure out where I went wrong?

Thanks!

```
<tr>
   <td><strong>Welcome!</strong></td>
   <td><a><input type="button" value="▶" onclick="play()">
   <audio id="audio" src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3740.mp3"></audio></a>Diluedinpe! 
    </td>
 </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>Good Evening</strong></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="▶" onclick="play()">
    <audio id="audio" src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3719.mp3"></audio>Butuku bulenaga</td>
  </tr>
```

```
    <script>
       function play() {
         var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
         audio.play();
       }
     </script>
```

Comment: You cannot use the same `id` (id="audio") for different elemets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in simple way you can pass audio tag id in onclick function and then get audio tag by passed id in function:

```
<tr>
   <td><strong>Welcome!</strong></td>
   <td><a><input type="button" value="▶" onclick="play('audio1')">
   <audio id="audio1" src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3740.mp3"></audio></a>Diluedinpe! 
    </td>
 </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>Good Evening</strong></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="▶" onclick="play('audio2')">
    <audio id="audio2" src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3719.mp3"></audio>Butuku bulenaga</td>
  </tr>
```

js:

```
<script>
    function play(audioId) {
       var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
       audio.play();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using same ID for audio.

Secondly, you are keeping many audios on single page. So when user clicks on multiple audios, all audios will play simultaneously which is not expected basically.

So playing one audio file at a time is best approach. ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvh7fg1z/1/))

You can try

```
<tr>
   <td><strong>Welcome!</strong></td>
   <td>
       Diluedinpe! 
     <audio preload="auto" controls  controlsList="nodownload" loop style="border:1px solid #000; border-radius:15px;">
        <source src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3740.mp3" />
    </audio>
   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><strong>Good Evening</strong></td>
  <td>
     Butuku bulenaga
    <audio preload="auto" controls  controlsList="nodownload" loop style="border:1px solid #000; border-radius:15px;">
        <source src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3719.mp3" />
    </audio>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And JS

With this Javascript, only one audio plays and other audios on same page get paused...

```
<script>  
document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
   var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
       if(audios[i] != e.target){
            audios[i].pause();
       }
    }
 }, true);
</script>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rvh7fg1z/1/)**

Comment: I like your suggestion, but would like to add a standard play button such as [link](https://us.123rf.com/450wm/4zevar/4zevar1509/4zevar150900035/44649773-play-button-icon.jpg?ver=6). I am experimenting, but is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Welcome!</strong></td>
            <td><a><input type="button" data-key="1" value="▶" onclick="play(this)">
                    <audio class="audio" data-key="1"
                        src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3740.mp3"></audio></a>Diluedinpe!
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Good Evening</strong></td>
            <td><input type="button" data-key="2" value="▶" onclick="play(this)">
                <audio class="audio" data-key="2"
                    src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3719.mp3"></audio>Butuku bulenaga
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        function play(val) {
            var audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${val.dataset.key}"]`);
            audio.play();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the onClick function with an argument that will specify the id of the audio you want to run.

```
<td>
  <a>
    <input type="button" value="▶" onclick="play(1)">
    <audio id="audio-1" src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3740.mp3">
    </audio>
  </a> Diluedinpe!
</td>
```

and in the function, you will just need to play the audio with the specified id

```
var audio = document.getElementById($`audio{id}`);
```